# How to insert elements to a sorted heap such that it remains sorted?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap

Inserting an element in sorted heap at the end takes **O(1)**. But I want to insert in such a way such that it remain sorted. Achieving this in **O(n)** is not a big deal.

**How can I take advantage of that it is sorted?** Finding Appropriate position via binary search will take **O(logn)**. But insertion via swapping will again be of Order n. **How I can reduce the time complexity?** Please help.

Comment: So, there is no connection to a binary heap, you simply want to insert element to a sorted array and the array should remain sorted. This is done in `O(n)`, no running away from it. see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorted_array).  You might want to consider a different data type such as a binary tree or a skip list.

Comment: You need a data structure which allows _cheap inserts_ like a linked list or a tree. (Not an array)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you normally insert into a heap, that is just a heap and not a sorted list:

A heap is a hirachical structure. Every element has up to 2 children. To insert, you just append at the end and then compare it to its parent, wich can be determined by the position of the element. If the parent is bigger, then you swap the parent with the new element. Repeat until either the new element is bigger than its parent, or the new element has become the first/top element. That way, the smallest element is always the first element.

This operation will take O(log n) operations at most.

After reading the comments, what you actually want is not a classical heap, but a sorted tree implemented using pointers or array indices. Search for `red black tree`.

Comment: A heap is not necessarily a sorted list. a heap is a heap, if each child is bigger than its parent.

Comment: it should be a heap is a min heap

Comment: suppose it is a sorted list.now after adding a node i want list to be in sorted order

Comment: @DeepakY4-YrBTechComputerS Do you want a min-heap, or a sorted list? Those are two different things.

Comment: I want the list to be sorted each time a new item is added